# Output a pd.DataFrame from a generator expression

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to return as output a complete Pandas DataFrame from a generator expression?
I made a simplified small data example below, but the sought solution should work for large data. Sure, concatenating multiple DataFrames can be done differently (using for ex. append), the present example just serves to comprehend how generator expressions work with DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

dat1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def genso(dat1):
    dat2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
    for i in range(10):
        dat1 = pd.concat([dat1, dat2])
    yield dat1

g = genso(df1)
```

One can now loop through the generator object and it will give a print output, not a DataFrame. So the question is, how to turn it into pd.DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think so...

Try:

```
df = next(g)

type(df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

and

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 110 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    110 non-null float64
B    110 non-null float64
C    110 non-null float64
D    110 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 4.3 KB
```